# SignalR Core can't connect from JS client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm following this guide [from MS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/). I created an MVC Core 2.0 app and added the package reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha1-final" />
```

I configured the Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }
```

and

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Statistics>("statistics");
        });

       ...
    }
```

Here is my StatisticsHub:

```
public class Statistics : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
    }
}
```

From my `HomeController` I have an Index action which returns this view:

```
<script src="js/signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js"></script>

<script>
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnection('/statistics');

    connection.on('send', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    connection.start()
        .then(() => connection.invoke('send', 'Hello'));
</script>
```

I also tried to include the
`<script src="js/signalr-clientES5-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js"></script>` client but there's no difference.

I start the app, firefox boots up and this is what happens in the console:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4tja.png)

I followed the guide step by step and I don't know why it doesn't connect.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? Hitting the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Unfortunately no.. Switched back to MVC5 because of this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
[HubName("Statistics")]
public class Statistics : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
    }
}
```

Script

```
<script>
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:xxxx/signalr";
        var statisticsHub = $.connection.Statistics;
    </script>
```

Or

```
<script>
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnection('http://localhost:xxxx');

    connection.on('send', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    connection.start()
        .then(() => connection.invoke('send', 'Hello'));
</script>
```

Where "xxxx: is the port number

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I put `[HubName("Statistics")]` on my Hub. I tried both of the scripts but unfortunately both give me a different error. First I would like to say that in my Layout I have the jquery includes which are auto generated. The thing I did was to update it from version 2.2.0 to 3.2.1. After the includes there is a section Scripts which is where I write my Index.cshtml code for the signalR connection. 

The first approach gives me a `$.connection is undefined` error. I console.log($) and I see that Jquery is loaded and I'm sure that the signalR-client is loaded after it.

Comment: The second approach gives me this error: `Error: Failed to start the connection. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` from `signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js:616:13`

Comment: I also tried `let connection = new signalR.HubConnection('/Statistics');` again with no success. I get these things in the console: `Information: Normalizing '/Statistics' to 'http://localhost:49567/Statistics'` and after it `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:49567/Statistics?id=85be5308-dfc7-487b-a2d2-c099302b850d.`

Comment: I forgot to ask... Did you included  <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>?

Comment: I didn't include it because it wasn't written in the guide. I tried including it after including the SignalR-client but Firefox says: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:49567/signalr/hubs”.`

Comment: Then it differ from a none core signalr. Remove the HubName attribute.
There is another approach to start a connection in a guide.
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:xxxx/statistics")
                .WithConsoleLogger()
.Build();
Have you tried it?

Comment: I removed the HubName attribute. Indeed in core it's different. I have made SignalR apps using MVC5 and I didn't have any problems. This approach that you listed, as far as I understand, is when you want a C# client which is not what I want. I want to connect to the SignalR from my index.cshtml using JS.

Comment: @Reath i have working code that does what you wanted here, let me know if you're still wanting it and i'll do you up a repo

Comment: Well I switched to MVC5 at the time because of this issue, but if I ever create a new Core project I'm sure it'll be of help not only for me.

Comment: @user326608 do you still have that repo please? I am running to the same trouble as Reath

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable cross origin if you have an isolated client.

In your startup `ConfigureServices` method, add `services.AddCors()`;